# Conditional filter using LINQ with C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I need to get a list of records and filter them based on a condition: if serviceId = 1 then I need to combine that result with the result for serviceId = 5.

Models:

```
public class Partner
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DbGeography Location { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PartnerServiceBrand> PartnerServiceBrands { get; set; }
}

public class PartnerServiceBrand
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Partner Partner { get; set; }
    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
}

public class Service
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PartnerServiceBrand> PartnerServiceBrands { get; set; }
}
```

My code for just one filter:

```
var serviceId = 1;

var partners = dbContext.Partners.Where(p => p.PartnerServiceBrands.Select(psb => psb.Service.Id).Contains(serviceId));
```

I tried to do:

```
if (serviceId == 1)
{
    var partners2 = dbContext.Partners.Where(p => p.PartnerServiceBrands.Select(psb => psb.Service.Id).Contains(5));

    partners = partners.Union(partners2);  // Error
}
```

I also tried to use `Contains` with a `List<int>`, but I was not able to get it up and running.

**EDIT**

The error I get is:

> Exception:Thrown: "The geography data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT   because it is not comparable." (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException)

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. What do you need in the first list? Do you want to get all the partners that have a Service with id = 1?

Comment: What error message you got?

Comment: @ataravati hi, I want to get all the partners that have the serviceId=5 joined with all the partners that have the serviceId=1

Comment: @techkid hi, sorry I have edited the question with the error and the missing property that is causing the error (public DbGeography Location { get; set; })

Answer (score 1):

My take on this.

Given the list of `serviceIds` that you want to filter on:

```
var serviceIds = new List<int>{1, 5};

var partners = dbContext.Services
    .Where(ser => serviceIds.Contains(ser.Id).SelectMany(ser => ser.PartnerServiceBrands)
    .Select(psb => psb.Partner).Distinct();
```

Comment: Hi, I have to add a ")" after the Contains(ser.Id) to avoid red editor underline, but in execution I get the error I have included in the question

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an error because `Union()` generates `UNION ALL` with `SELECT DISTINCT`. As an aside `Concat()` produces just a `UNION ALL`.

In any case, I think you should be able to get what you're looking for with something like below:

```
var serviceIds = new List<int>{ 1, 5 };
var partners = dbContext.Partners
    .Where(p => p.PartnerServiceBrands.Any(psb => serviceIds.Contains(psb.Service.Id))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will works:

```
var partners = dbContext.Services
    .Where(ser => ser.Id == 1 || s.Id == 5).SelectMany(ser => ser.PartnerServiceBrands)
    .Select(psb => psb.Partner).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `DbSet<Service>` as `Services`, I would try :

```
var serviceId = ...;

var partners = dbContext.Services
      .Where(svc => svc.Id == serviceId || (serviceId == 1 && svc.Id == 5))
      .SelectMany(svc => svc.PartnerServiceBrands)
      .Select(psb => psb.Partner).Distinct();
```

Comment: I get repeated partners :(